# Uncheck or turn off all checkbox based toggle switches when a new one is turned on?

Tags: css, checkbox, toggle, toggleswitch

I am using some CSS3 toggle switches in a project of mine and they are currently toggling just fine, but what i would like to have happen is for all other toggles to turn off when a new one is activated. Can anyone help get me started on this. I am not even sure where to start. These are the toggles I am using:

http://wsnippets.com/styling-checkbox-toggle-switches-css3/

is there a way for Javascript to be able to do this? Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, this will do the trick:

```
$(function() {
  $('.checkbox-switch input').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(".checkbox-switch input").prop('checked', false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

See the demo using the example html/css in your link here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MymGqP.

Comment: WOW!! Thank you! That works perfectly and a much simpler solution than I was chasing. THanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. They are just checkboxes hidden under some styling, so you can deal with them like any other checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your project, one solution could be to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes for your toggle switches. That way, the default behaviour of the radio buttons will deselect the other/s when a new one is activated.

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that but I also need the user to be able to have them all off at the same time.

Comment: A jQuery method to do this could look comething like 

`$('input.class').on('change', function({$('input.class').not(this).prop('checked', false);});`