# how to uncheck all Toggle Switch when one toggle switch is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone tell me how can I change the other Toggle Switches to unchecked when I checked one of the toggle switch. I can do with checkbox but I found it very tricky with Javascript Toggle Switch

```
        if (this.checked) {
          $(":checkbox[value=switch-intermediate]").removeAttr("checked", null);
          $(":checkbox[value=switch-expert]").removeAttr("Checked",null);
        }
```

My code above works with checkbox but not Toggle Switch. I did see some other examples online from slack overflow like this one - [Uncheck or turn off all checkbox based toggle switches when a new one is turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192286/uncheck-or-turn-off-all-checkbox-based-toggle-switches-when-a-new-one-is-turned)
But when I follow it, it still doesn't work. Thank you!

[jfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/jt100/4xjf1ano/3/)

Comment: declare the current checkbox, `let selected = this;` Then in your if statement make your selection but also choose to `.not()` included the selected checkbox. `$(":checkbox[value=switch-intermediate], :checkbox[value=switch-expert]").not(selected).removeAttr("checked", null);`  --- https://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: I try your method, it still doesn't work. This is what I tried - https://jsfiddle.net/jt100/4xjf1ano/25/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With simple `change` event and `.not(this)`

- By using `$(".switch:not([checked])")` no need to check `if(this.checked)`
- To change `checked/unchecked` use `.prop("checked" , true/false)`
- To prevent `this` checkbox from unchecked when unchecked others use `.not(this)`

```js
$(".switch:not([checked])").on('change' , function(){
  $(".switch").not(this).prop("checked" , false);
});
```

```css
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #5c13ec;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #5c13ec;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-two">
  <div>Novice</div>
  <label class="switch-label">
    <input class="switch" id="switch-novice" value="switch-novice"  type="checkbox"/>
     <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="toggle-three">
  <div>Intermediate</div>
  <label class="switch-label">
    <input class="switch" id="switch-intermediate" value="switch-intermediate"  type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="toggle-four">
  <div>Expert</div>
  <label class="switch-label">
    <input class="switch" id="switch-expert" value="switch-expert" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

- Also if you've more switch s on another places .. you can use `$(this).closest('CONTAINER').find('.switch').not(this)........` instead of `$('.switch').not(this).....` [**SEE Example HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/dna5er1t/4/)

Comment: Thanks @CodeNinja you're totally welcome .. Also if you've more `switch` s on another places .. you can use `$(this).parent().find('.switch').not(this)........`  .. have a nice day :)

Comment: NVM @CodeNinja you're welcome .. **BUT** you need to know that not all demos works here should work on a real website then you can talk to the person who post the answer and ask for help .. simple and easy ;) .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @CodeNinja sorry for `.parent()` it should be `.closest()` .. see my updated answer with the example

Answer (score 0):

Change the inputs from checkboxes to radio buttons, and add a `name="something"` to each radio button, using the same "something" name on all the related buttons.

Basically, each input changes from this

```
<input class="switch" id="switch-novice"
       value="switch-novice" type="checkbox" />
```

to this

```
<input class="switch" id="switch-novice"
       value="switch-novice" type="radio" name="switch-choice" />
```

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/drum8xgp/3/)